# Preferred way to implement Persistable.isNew for entity with predefined ID in Spring Data

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The entity is Tile, that uniquely identified with it's coordinates on a map:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

@Entity
class Tile implements Persistable<Tile.Coordinates> {
   @Embeddable
   public static class Coordinates implements Serializable {
       long x;
       long y;
       public Coordinates(x,y){this.x=x; this.y=y;}
   }

   @EmbeddedId Coordinates coordinates;

   private Tile(){}
   public Tile(long x,long y) {this.coordinates=new Coordinates(x,y);}

   @Override
   public boolean isNew(){
      // what is preferred implementation? 
   }
   // other code
}
```

Tile coordinates are predefined, because Tile without coordinates is senseless.

```
Tile tile=new Tile(x,y);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on which kind of ID your attribute has.

First you will need to put the annotation `@Transient` on your `isNew()` method.

If you id is a `Long` (or any other object) you can check to see if `id == null`. If your id is a `long` (or any other primitive) you will need to check if `id == 0`.

In the entity that you posted there is an embedded id, and do not do only the if embedded == null because the JPA will check the attributes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a preferred way.

I guess you could, for example, implement a version column and initialize with 1, your `isNew()` could `return version == 1;`

I'm sure there are other ways to do it as well.